# TravisCI build continues to fail even after changing alpine version

Tags: docker, dockerfile, travis-ci, node.js, alpine

So I ran my Docker build with TravisCI and I got a failure like so:

```
FAIL src/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run
    TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of object '#<process>'
      at exports.default (node_modules/jest-util/build/create_process_object.js:15:34)
```

I did not think that this `App.test.js` file would give me problems after I removed the logic from within the `it` block like so:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

it("renders without crashing", () => {});
```

I thought the issue may have been the latest release of `node` because I saw others have similar error messages, so I changed my version like so:

`FROM node:10.15-alpine as builder` OR `FROM node:10.15-alpine` as I have various `Dockerfile`s for each service I am building as this is a multi-container project.

That change I made did not resolve the issue, TravisCI continues to fail my build with the same exact error, what gives here?

I thought perhaps the issue would be a version of Jest mismatch, but I have not installed any version of Jest, this is my `package.json` file inside my `client/src/App.test.js`:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "axios": "0.18.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

None of the solutions above have helped me. You cannot upgrade Jest because react-scripts comes with version 23.x so you are just adding on top of what react-scripts would already have. You cannot upgrade react-scripts so that it will have jest@24 because the latest version has jest@23.

Changing to v11.10.1 does not help either and within my Dockerfile I have tried changing the 'FROM' in my `Dockerfile` to `FROM node:10.15-alpine` and that has not helped.

When I tested it in this manner:

`docker run -it --rm -v $(PWD):$(PWD) -w $(PWD) node:10.15-alpine npm test`

it passed!

```
 PASS  src/App.test.js (10.163s)

  ✓ renders without crashing (5ms)
```

But it does not pass in TravisCI

This is my `Dockerfile` for my `client/src` directory:

```
FROM node:10.15-alpine as builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 3000
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I even tried changing my `.travis.yml` file to this:

`- docker run -it --rm -v myproject/react-test node:10.15-alpine npm test -- --coverage`,

when it was originally this:

```
script:
  - docker run myproject/react-test npm test -- --coverage
```

Absolutely nothing appears to be working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rely on `FROM node:10.15-alpine` alone to fix this. I had to go with the fix from the facebook team. So if anyone else did not get a fix from modifying your `Dockerfile` to `node:10.15-alpine`, go to your `package.json` file and change react-scripts to the following facebook fix:

`"react-scripts": "3.0.0-next.b0cbf2ca"`

Then go ahead and remove your `node_modules/` folder via `rm -rf node_modules` and then run `npm install`, check your `jest-util` file, it should now have an output like this:

```
└─┬ react-scripts@3.0.0-next.b0cbf2ca
  ├─┬ babel-jest@24.5.0
  │ └─┬ @jest/transform@24.5.0
  │   ├─┬ jest-haste-map@24.5.0
  │   │ └── jest-util@24.5.0  deduped
  │   └── jest-util@24.5.0
  └─┬ jest@24.5.0
    └─┬ jest-cli@24.5.0
      ├─┬ @jest/core@24.5.0
      │ ├─┬ @jest/reporters@24.5.0
      │ │ └── jest-util@24.5.0  deduped
      │ ├─┬ jest-runner@24.5.0
      │ │ └── jest-util@24.5.0  deduped
      │ ├─┬ jest-runtime@24.5.0
      │ │ └── jest-util@24.5.0  deduped
      │ ├── jest-util@24.5.0  deduped
      │ └─┬ jest-watcher@24.5.0
      │   └── jest-util@24.5.0  deduped
      ├─┬ jest-config@24.5.0
      │ ├─┬ jest-environment-jsdom@24.5.0
      │ │ └── jest-util@24.5.0  deduped
      │ ├─┬ jest-environment-node@24.5.0
      │ │ └── jest-util@24.5.0  deduped
      │ ├─┬ jest-jasmine2@24.5.0
      │ │ ├─┬ jest-each@24.5.0
      │ │ │ └── jest-util@24.5.0  deduped
      │ │ └── jest-util@24.5.0  deduped
      │ └── jest-util@24.5.0  deduped
      └── jest-util@24.5.0  deduped
```

You should be good to run TravisCI build now. The issue is the react-scripts version `2.1.8` is conflicting with new version of Node. Suffered through this all day long, grateful to the facebook team for getting back to me.

For reference: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6475